# Animated TV show with a guy and his pet green monster named Brock, which was given to him by his grandfather

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

There's a TV show that I watched when I was a kid about a guy having a pet green monster that had two horns and was named Brock. (It's not *Pokémon*) The monster originally belonged to his grandfather. Later something happened to the monster and he got wings.

I also remember the main character having brown hair and there where two other people with him. There was one time where they went to the Ocean and they took out the monster and the people knew it was the grandfather's and thought he stole it.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [Magi-Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series)).

The series centers on a young boy from Earth who travels to the Moonlands, a mystical world full of monsters and such, thanks to a ring given to him by his grandfather, who previously traveled there.

His companion is Furok, which sounds similar to Brock, and he is blue with horns, and at least at one point, as seen in this image, flies:

[image: blue four-legged animal with blue wings, white facial hair, and orange horns carries several passengers on his back across a yellow sky]

The plot you describe where he's accused of stealing the monster seems to occur in the episode "The Depths of Courage" according to a [fan wiki synopsis](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/The_Depths_of_Courage):

> When Tony summons Furok, the Orotheans gather in amazement, they tell him that Furok is the same one used by the Magi who vanquished the Cawh, the magi was Spencer Jones, Tony's Grandfather. An Orothean named Borse accuses Tony of stealing Furok and challenges him. Borse defeats Tony with his Allio and declares Tony an imposter.

Comment: user111614, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved and reward both you and starpilotsix with some reputation :)